# Unexpected question 'enter PIN for "Kryptonite iOS"' while doing git pull after updating to MacOS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: macos, catalina, ssh, git

Most of my Bitbucket git repos can't be pushed/fetched after upgrading to MacOS 10.15.4. All git origins are SSH (not HTTPS). I get this question in terminal when doing `git pull` and other commands:

> enter PIN for "Kryptonite iOS"

I have never ever had an iOS device in my life. I have never ever dealt with Kryptonite (but used Krypton).

What is going on and how to get back my git repos?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found so far.

When terminal is asking for "Kryptonite iOS" it is actually asking for Bitbucket 2FA one time password. I tested.

How I fixed:

- Go to Bitbucket -> profile -> Atlassian Account.
- Logout, log back in. (Yeah, this was necessary.)
- Change password. (Old password didn't work for some reason.)
- In git repo switch from SSH to HTTP origin. `git remote set-url origin https://you@bitbucket.org/org/project.git` (This will stop asking the above question, but will start asking for the new password.)

Hope this will help someone.